# Difference between Reply-To address and From address in an email

Tags: email, mailx

In Heirloom `mailx`, one can specify "from address" (`-r`) and "reply-to address" (`-R`). What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From RFC 2822 para 3.6.2:

> When the "Reply-To:" field is present, it indicates the mailbox(es) to
>   which the author of the message suggests that replies be sent.  In the
>   absence of the "Reply-To:" field, replies SHOULD by default be sent to
>   the mailbox(es) specified in the "From:" field unless otherwise
>   specified by the person composing the reply.

You can compose and send an email (from you) and have the reply sent to some other mailbox (your secretary maybe) or a group mailbox.

Answer (score 1):

The FROM address identifies who is sending the message.  Normally this is where someone will send a reply, but you can specify a different address where you want replies to go.  This may be useful for example, when posting to a mailing list and you want people replying to your message to send to the mailing list rather than directly to you.